# Octave 5.1.0 no longer supports copy of figures to clipboard

Tags: octave, gnu

In Octave 5.1.0 (the latest as of today) ,I can no longer copy figures into the clipboard (I'm using 64 bit octave on win 10).
I came across this [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55970), that describe the issue but haven't found any fix.
Is there any known fix or workaround to this problem ?

Comment: You can usr Alt+PrintScrn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default graphics toolkit in Octave 5.1.0 is "**qt**" now. qt graphics toolkit does not have "copy to clipboard" feature. You can change graphics toolkit to "**gnuplot**", which have this feature:

```
 graphics_toolkit ('gnuplot')
 plot(1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After making an inquiry on the report for [bug #55970](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55970), it appears that it is possible to re-enable the menu copy function.  That report references an earlier [bug #55795](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55795), that was closed after a patch to make all figure windows the same across toolkits. This apparently eliminated the Copy function from the Qt version as well.

A patch has now been submitted on the [bug #55970](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55970) tracker to re-enable a copy function. This patch involves both m-file and cc-file changes, though, so making use of this patch will involve re-compiling octave yourself, or waiting for a version to be released that includes the patch.